# add several references to the same record in navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my EF 6 Model First application, I have an entity with a many-to-many navigation property to another entity. In the first entity, I need to add several references to the same record in navigation property.

The first entity is a “saleslistItem” and the second entity is “warehouseItem”. Normally there will be a one-to-one relationship here, but exceptionally there will be some bundles where one “saleslistItem” contains several “warehouseItems”. “WarehouseItem” can also be included in several “salesListItems”. At the end of the project, my customer says, testing it, that “saleslistItem” must be able to consist of several “WarehouseItems” of the same kind (like two boxes of smoked ham).

These data is used several places in my code. (ie. doing a sale removes items from the warehouse) If I could just add several the same reference, my code would work without any modifications. But in the implementation of the navigation property the “hashtable”-collection is used, and this collection requires unique entries. Is there a workaround here? Performance is irrelevant as the data amount is small.

If there are no such workaround, is it possible to store values together with the instance of navigation property? Maybe it is implemented as a field in the join-table???

Any other suggestions?
Need a solution so the customer pays the last part of the bill!

Answer (score 0):

So you currently have a `1`:`1` from `SalesListItem to`WarehouseItem`via a ForeignKey in`SalesListItem`? Sounds like you need:

```
public class SalesListItem
{
    public virutal ICollection<SalesListWarehouseItem> WareHouseItems { get; set; }
}

public class SalesListWarehouseItem
{
    public virtual SalesListItem Parent{ get; set; }
    public virtual WarehouseItem WarehouseItem { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; } // maybe double?
}
```

Comment: No, I have a many-to-many relation, but it normally will be a 1:1 relation (about 90% of the relations are 1:1). Your solution can be used anyhow. Thanks. But first I will try to swap the usage of `Hashset` to another collection. This will allow several references to the same warehouseItem. I will report back here to tell about the result. But first I will celebrate Christmas. Happy Christmas!

Comment: Hehe, thanks let me know how it goes with a different collection. I am guessing you already have a joining table then, possibly without defining it directly? Merry Christmas to you too :-D

Comment: Back after Christmas break, and I have figured out the following: The join-table that EF generates cannot contain more than one reference from one record to another. Consequently, I cannot have several references from one source record to the same destination record in my navigation property. I cannot let one SaleListItem point to the same WarehouseProduct several times. I have to rewrite part of the application.

Comment: What is the PK on the generated joining table? What about adding that table as an entity in its current form, and then changing it to have an ID identity PK. Then you will be able to have many references.

Comment: PK is a clustered key consisiting of the FK to SalesListItem and to the WarehouseItem They are both int. This is how it is generated by EF 6 using model first. I do not want to change this. I could have added an extra field in this table called "GoIntoWithAmount" and, done som mapping trickery etc, but it is no longer a simple thing and I will alter a generated code. I better change my code.